# Custom validator, cb is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Problem with a custom validator in node.js, using mongoose. I'm trying to check if a `query` exists in `headerLog` prior to inserting it.

My code is below:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose'); //layer above mongodb
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var headerLogSchema = new Schema({
    query: { type: String, required: true, unique: true, validate: {
          validator: function(v, cb) {
            HeaderLog.find({query: v}, function(err, documents){
               cb(documents.length == 0);
            });
          },
          message: 'Header already exists in log, didnt save this one.'
        }
    }
})

var HeaderLog = mongoose.model('headerLog', headerLogSchema);

module.exports = HeaderLog;
```

The error: `TypeError: cb is not a function`.

I'm calling this function like so:

```
function logHeader(query) {
  var newHeaderLog = new HeaderLog({
    query: query
  })

  newHeaderLog.save(function(err) {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
    else {
      console.log('New header logged');
    }
  });
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [the reference](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/validation.html#async-custom-validators) states, asynchronous validators should either have `isAsync` flag:

```
validate: {
  isAsync: true,
  validator: function(v, cb) { ... }
}
```

Or return a promise. Since the validator already uses another model, and Mongoose models are promise-based, it makes sense to use existing promise:

```
  validator: function(v) {
    return HeaderLog.find({query: v}).then(documents => !documents.length);
  }
```

[`countDocuments`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.countDocuments) is a better alternative to `find` for cases when only documents count is needed.

Comment: Thanks. This worked, I'm using the promise based solution. Is there any way to print `err.message` without "headerLog validation failed". When I print `err.message` I get: "headerLog validation failed: query: Header already exists in log, didnt save this one."

Comment: You could cut it out with regexp. But the point of validation errors is that they are stored separately as err.errors, so they could be associated with their fields. Just use `err.errors` and format it as you wish.

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the async validator example [here in the doc](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/validation.html#async-custom-validators), it looks like you have to pass the option `isAsync: true` in order to tell mongoose that you are using an async validator and thus it should pass a callback to it.

```
var headerLogSchema = new Schema({
    query: { 
       type: String, 
       required: true, 
       unique: true, 
       validate: {
          isAsync: true,                   // <======= add this
          validator: function(v, cb) {
            HeaderLog.find({query: v}, function(err, documents){
               cb(documents.length == 0);
            });
          },
          message: 'Header already exists in log, didnt save this one.'
        }
    }
})
```